# Amazon Web Service EMR FileSystem

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elastic-map-reduce

I am trying to run a job on an AWS EMR cluster. The problem Im getting is the following:

aws java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs

I dont know where exactly my problem resides (in my java jar job or in the configurations of the job)

In my S3 bucket Im making a folder (input) and in it im putting a bunch of files with my data. Then in the arguments Im giving the path for the input folder which then same path is used as the FileInputPath.getInputPath(args[0]).

My question is - First will the job grab all files in the input folder and work on them all or I have to supply all of the paths of each file?

Second question - How can I solve the above Exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep your input files in S3 . e.g. s3://mybucket/input/
Keep all your file to be pressed in input folder under my bucket.

In you map reduce use code as below

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,"s3n://mybucket/input/")
```

This will automatically process all files under input folder.

Comment: How do you persist new files into the same dir afterwords?