# how to use emrfs as a regular filesystem on apache spark over aws emr

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-emr

I am using amazon emr and running python code using spark submit.

I would like to be able to access the EMRFS filesystem as an actual file system, meaning that I would like to be able to list all the files using something like

```
import os 
os.listdir()
```

and would like to save files into the local storage  and have them persisted in the s3 bucket.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460177/amazon-web-service-emr-filesystem) which is old and seems to work only with Java and I had no luck utilizing it for python, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154896/create-emr-5-3-0-with-emrfs-s3-bucket-as-storage), which is more general, old and does not fit my needs.

How can I do that?

Comment: the best i can think of is.. 

 1. Either enable HDFS and use hdfs:// protocol. Or instead of 
 2. or directly use s3:// instead
 3. or AWS has hbase backed by s3 --looks like u r looking out for this

Comment: @ravi did you ever do it? if so, please provide a code example? I did not manage to do so but it sounds great

Comment: 1. https://supergloo.com/spark/apache-spark-amazon-s3/ this link should give u how to use spark with s3; when u spin EMR, make sure u select hadoop and hdfs checkboxes (via advanced link in the top) ; 
2. in which case u can replace all s3:// with hdfs:// and get the same spark job running. 
3. Hbase on s3 is in this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hbase-s3.html --i havent tried this though